# Add support of GTP to OVS 2.4 versiom

Tags: tunnel, openflow

Im looking for the **GTP tunnel creation in OVS switch** source code from git.
Please advice me if there are any Packages of GTP implementation  available that can be use with OVS. Or how to start for doing this from scratch.

**Functionalities:**
1.Matching for GTP tunnel header parameters
2.Tunneling of packets.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by creating Handler for GTP like how did for VXLAN.